# What is the best GUI library for blackberry java development?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me, custom-controls

What do you think is the most comprehensive and stable GUI library for Blackberry java development? I am currently using J4ME, anyone has any other experiences? A good GUI library should also have support for like grid controls, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I donot think we have anything more advanced graphically.
I had to code for makin a grid control I remember.
Even the controls which exist doesn't look very good.
So I try making/using my own Custom modified controls everytime according to the theme.

http://www.just2me.com/2008/01/j2me-gui-libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I have found to do it is to roll your own, use the currently available TextField, LabelField etc. as the base and then make it look how you need it.